# How can I vectorize the following four for-loops in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

I have to construct a matrix of size `(Nx*Ny, Nx*Ny)` where `Nx` and `Ny` can be larger than 100. Currently I am using four for-loop which makes the initialization of my final matrix "matrix_result" (with dimension `(Nx*Ny, Nx*Ny)`) very slow.

The first two loops are over all elements in the array xs and ys. The second two loops are again over the same elements in xs and ys. Then I construct the x-index and y-index of the matrix_result with `matrix_idx = idx_y1 + Ny * idx_x` and  `matrix_idy = idx_y2 + Ny * idx_x2`.

Here is the full code. How is it possible to vectorize these initialization of the matrix "matrix_result"?

```
import numpy as np

Nx = 100
Ny = 100

xs = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, Nx)
ys = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, Ny)

matrix_result = np.zeros((Nx * Ny, Nx * Ny))

for idx_x1 in range(Nx):
    for idx_y1 in range(Ny):

    # Get values of the arrays xs and ys
    x1 = xs[idx_x1]
    y1 = ys[idx_y1]

    # Compute arctan2 of y1 and x1
    argument1 = np.arctan2(y1, x1)

    for idx_x2 in range(Nx):
        for idx_y2 in range(Ny):

            if idx_x1 != idx_x2 or idx_y1 != idx_y2:

                # Get values of the arrays xs and ys
                x2 = xs[idx_x2]
                y2 = ys[idx_y2]

                # Compute arctan2 of y1 and x1
                argument2 = np.arctan2(y2, x2)

                # Compute the elements of the matrix matrix_results.
                distance_12 = np.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
                matrix_element = np.cos(argument2 - argument1) * np.exp(distance_12)

                # Construct indices of the matrix matrix_result with dimension (Nx * Ny, Nx * Ny)
                matrix_idx = idx_y1 + Ny * idx_x1
                matrix_idy = idx_y2 + Ny * idx_x2

                # Insert elements into matrix
                matrix_result[matrix_idx, matrix_idy] = matrix_element
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def vectorised_calculation(xs, xy):
    Nx = len(xs)
    Ny = len(ys)
    matrix_result = np.zeros((Nx * Ny, Nx * Ny))

    indices = np.indices([Nx,Ny,Nx,Ny])
    #Remove those sets of indices that do not satisfy the following condition
    mask = np.logical_or(indices[0] != indices[2], indices[1] != indices[3])
    indices = indices[:, mask]

    x1 = xs[indices[0]]
    y1 = ys[indices[1]]
    x2 = xs[indices[2]]
    y2 = ys[indices[3]]
    argument1 = np.arctan2(y1,x1)
    argument2 = np.arctan2(y2,x2)
    
    # Compute the elements of the matrix matrix_results.
    distance_12 = np.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
    matrix_element = np.cos(argument2 - argument1) * np.exp(distance_12)
        
    # Construct indices of the matrix matrix_result with dimension (Nx * Ny,     Nx *     Ny)
    matrix_idx = indices[1] + Ny * indices[0]
    matrix_idy = indices[3] + Ny * indices[2]
        
    # Insert elements into matrix
    matrix_result[matrix_idx, matrix_idy] = matrix_element

    return matrix_result
```

I found it hard work to interpret the question but as far as I can tell this does what you're asking.

In general you can use np.indices to vectorise sets of nested for loops.

```
xs = np.random.rand(40)
ys = np.random.rand(40)
s = time.time()
func1(xs, ys)
print("time taken for original:", time.time() - s)
s = time.time()
func2(xs, ys)
print("time taken for vectorised:", time.time() - s)
```

time taken for original: 19.610620737075806

time taken for vectorised: 0.3943142890930176

With:

```
xs = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, 100)
```

you get the following output when using plt.imshow:

[image: plt.imshow]

Comment: The code answers my question! Sorry for not being clear when asking. I have a 2D grid (the `xs` and `ys`). Instead of the 2D grid I had to define a new 2D grid which contains all the points of the 2D grid points as its x-coordinate (and similar for y-coordinate such that the new dimension is `(Nx * Ny, Nx * Ny)`). At same time the elements of the new matrix still depend on the "old" 2D grid. Thanks for the great answer!